# Can't have package and class with same name in Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, class, netbeans, package

I made a project in Eclipse. It works perfectly. I have about 5 classes in a single package - called foobar. One of the classes is called FooBar.

So far, so good.

Afterwards, I created a new project in Netbeans. Created a package with the name foobar, and the same 5 classes (just copy-pasting the code).

Now I get an error (in Netbeans) in the FooBar class: "Duplicate class". I made sure I only have one definition of the class, and the only logical explanation is that it would collide with the package name.

What can I do about it? (excluding renaming the classes/package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically if you have two packages within one workspace, then it will throw an error of duplicate names as you could potentially import a class from another package

E.g. import Foobar.foobar;

This would allow you to access public methods and variable declarations within a class in another package.

Either rename one of the packages, or create a new workspace.